# how are pipelined requests handled on the server side in python?

Tags: python, rest, httpwebrequest, pipeline

Can some one explain me how pipelined requests are treated on a server in python (or any other scripting language)?

Suppose I have web services made in python callable by iOS client. The client pipelines the requests and sends them to server. How can I receive and handle these requests on the server and send the appropriate response?

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Comment: well consider this scenario there are several web services exposed to the client. instead of calling one by one client create a pipeline of 5 web services and call that batch instead of calling them individually. how will server handle this request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTTP Pipelining

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_pipelining) and [Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/http/pipelining-faq.html) have good pipelining explanations. The following picture basically says it all.

[image: "Schema of non-pipelined vs. pipelined connection." - Wikipedia]

Normally (without pipelining), the client sends a request to the server and waits for a response before sending another request. With pipelining, however, the client sends multiple requests without waiting for the server's response.

### So, what does my server have to do to implement pipelining?

Actually, not much. All a server has to do to support pipelining is ensure that "that network buffers are not discarded between requests" (wikipedia). All HTTP/1.1 servers support pipelining.

[The client is responsible](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.2.2) for the bulk of the error handling (resending packets, etc.) and other headaches that come with implementing pipelining.